# EF Code First incorrectly renaming table, is this a bug?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-migration

I have two entities, Customer and Email. I have stripped them to only show what is important.

```
public class Customer
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [StringLength(6)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Relationships
    public ICollection<Email> MainEmails { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Email> OrderEmails { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Email> InvoiceEmails { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Email> APEmails { get; set; }
}

public class Email
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(50)]  
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Customer> MainCustomers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Customer> OrderCustomers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Customer> InvoiceCustomers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Customer> APCustomers { get; set; }
}
```

I override the OnModelCreating() in my context class and it includes the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasMany(e => e.MainEmails)
    .WithMany(c => c.MainCustomers)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("CustomerMainEmails");
        m.MapLeftKey("CustomerId");
        m.MapRightKey("Address");
    });

modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasMany(e => e.OrderEmails)
    .WithMany(c => c.OrderCustomers)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("CustomerOrderEmails");
        m.MapLeftKey("CustomerId");
        m.MapRightKey("Address");
    });

modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasMany(e => e.InvoiceEmails)
    .WithMany(c => c.InvoiceCustomers)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("CustomerInvoiceEmails");
        m.MapLeftKey("CustomerId");
        m.MapRightKey("Address");
    });

modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasMany(e => e.APEmails)
    .WithMany(c => c.APCustomers)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("CustomerAPEmails");
        m.MapLeftKey("CustomerId");
        m.MapRightKey("Address");
    });
```

This works fine and Creates FIVE tables in the DB, Customers, Emails, and the four M2M tables, CustomerAPEmails, CustomerInvoiceEmails, CustomerMainEmails, and CustomerOrderEmails.

Now, if I try to rename the Email entity to CustomerEmail and perform a migration, the first few lines in the migration are this:

```
RenameTable(name: "dbo.CustomerMainEmails", newName: "CustomerEmails");
DropForeignKey("dbo.CustomerMainEmails", "CustomerId", "dbo.Customers");
DropForeignKey("dbo.CustomerMainEmails", "Address", "dbo.Emails");
DropForeignKey("dbo.CustomerOrderEmails", "CustomerId", "dbo.Customers");
```

Doing an update-database then fails with this error:

*System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot find the object "dbo.CustomerMainEmails" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.*

I think the reason is the table is renamed, then it tries to drop keys on a table that doesn't exist. This seems to be in error to me. Is it a bug? Why does it rename the dbo.CustomerMainEmails table to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

Try to move the `RenameTable()` method below

```
DropForeignKey("dbo.CustomerMainEmails", "CustomerId", "dbo.Customers");
DropForeignKey("dbo.CustomerMainEmails", "Address", "dbo.Emails");
DropForeignKey("dbo.CustomerOrderEmails", "CustomerId", "dbo.Customers");
RenameTable(name: "dbo.CustomerMainEmails", newName: "CustomerEmails");
```

Comment: Thanks, but it shouldn't rename that table at all.

Comment: I am trying to figure out why that RenameTable line is even being generated. Thanks.

Comment: Just came across the same issue. Problem is you also need to worry about Down() method. And that has RenameTable at the end and referencing new name in prior statements. Sure looks like a bug.

Comment: FWIW, I experienced the same thing, only I had created a new table, and the migration was going to rename a totally unrelated table.  I modified the migration file before doing the update-database (I use Update-Database -Script and run the generated script).  Not sure what the conditions for this were, though.  Be sure to double check the migration code before updating, is all I can say :)

Comment: @PaulZaczkowski Same exact thing for me. Created a new table and migration auto-generated a line to rename an unrelated table. No clue how to determine why it thinks the table needs to be renamed.

Comment: @JustinSkiles to add to my issue, I tried removing the renaming lines, so that I wouldn't have to modify my stored procs that depended on it, and things got even more broken from that point (yay).  I wish I had time to dig into it more, and see exactly what's going on.

Comment: @PaulZaczkowski For what it's worth, I experienced the same thing again. I removed the added lines, but the EF still believed the rename had occur and all queries generated were brokenly referring to the wrong rename.

Comment: @PaulZaczkowski same thing is happening to me – specifically, join tables that were created automatically that are not themselves part of my model. Is this a known issue? This question is the only reference to it which i've found.